# access to "data" jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-tageditor

i'm creating a tag system for my backend.
all scripts (i'm using tagEditor) use jquery autocomplete to create an ajax suggest.

something like this:

```
$("#post-tags").tagEditor({ 
    autocomplete: { 
        'source': '/ajax.cfm?action=tag.search', 
        minLength: 3,
        placeholder: 'Enter tags ...'
    }
});
```

now, i would access to "data" option of my autocomplete.
by docs, something like this (i need to use _renderItem method):

```
$("#post-tags").data( 'autocomplete' )._renderItem = function( ul, item )  {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
}
```

how can i access to autocomplete data if widget is instantiated by another plugin?

many thanks

Comment: The widget's data should be stored under its full name (including the namespace: `uiAutocomplete`/`ui-autocomplete`). What's tagEditor? Could you make an example eg. a fiddle?